# An app operating under Windows 10 finds a byteOrderMarkUtf8 in a string, but there isn't one in the string

Tags: vb.net

I have an app that receives an XML string and tries to clean it up before processing.  For some reason, under the Windows 10 operating system, the app thinks there is a byteOrderMarkUtf8 leading the string. There isn't one.
The first character is "<". The app removes the "<", and then removes the rest of the tag, too, creating an invalid XML.
This used to work under Windows 7.

In the code below, I have commented the offending section out.
Is there something about character encoding that has changed with Windows 10 that would be causing this?

```
Private Sub CleanXML(ByRef InString As String)

    '   This subroutine cleans trash characters out of XML streams
    If (InString = "") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Null String passed to CleanXML." & vbCr & _
            "String Length: " & InString.Length & vbCr & _
            "Instring: " & InString & vbCr)
    End If

    If (InString.Length = 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("String of 0 length or null String passed to CleanXML." & vbCr & _
            "String Length: " & InString.Length & vbCr & _
            "Instring: " & InString & vbCr)
    End If

    Dim CleanString As String = InString

    CleanString = CleanString.Trim()                 ' Trim leading and trailing spaces
    CleanString = CleanString.Replace("- ", "")      ' Replace the dashes
    CleanString = CleanString.Replace("  <", "<")    ' Replace some white space
    CleanString = CleanString.Replace(" <", "<")     ' Replace some white space
    CleanString = CleanString.Replace("-<", "<")     ' Replace dash+lessthan with lessthan
    CleanString = CleanString.Replace("- <", "<")    ' Replace dash+space+lessthan with lessthan
    CleanString = CleanString.Replace("&", "&amp;")  ' Replace & with &amp;
    Dim Tempstring As String = ""
    If CleanString.Length > 0 Then
        Try
            Dim byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble())

            ' This is the offending code that I have commented out. 
            '-------------------------------------------------------------
            'If (CleanString.StartsWith(byteOrderMarkUtf8)) Then
            '    CleanString = CleanString.Remove(0, byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length)
            'End If
            'If (CleanString.EndsWith(byteOrderMarkUtf8)) Then
            '    CleanString = CleanString.Remove(CleanString.Length - 1, byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length)
            'End If
            '-------------------------------------------------------------

            '   Make sure the first and last characters are "<" and ">".
            Tempstring = CleanString
            Do Until (CleanString.StartsWith("<") Or (CleanString.Length = 0))
                CleanString = CleanString.Remove(0, 1)
            Loop
            Do Until (CleanString.EndsWith(">") Or (CleanString.Length = 0))
                CleanString = CleanString.Remove(CleanString.Length - 1, 1)
            Loop
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error in CleanXML." & vbCr & _
                            "String Length: " & CleanString.Length & vbCr & _
                            "Instring: " & InString & vbCr & _
                            "CleanString: " & CleanString & _
                            " Length: " & CleanString.Length.ToString)
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " Inner exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message)
            MessageBox.Show(Tempstring)
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Clean string of 0 length in CleanXML." & vbCr & _
                        "String Length: " & CleanString.Length & vbCr & _
                        "Instring: " & InString & vbCr & _
                        "CleanString: " & CleanString)
    End If

    '  Remove any BOMs (Byte-Order Marks) from the string.
    'Dim i As Integer = InStr(1, CleanString, byteOrderMarkUtf8)
    'Do Until i = 0
    '    CleanString = CleanString.Remove(i - 1, byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length)
    '    i = InStr(i, CleanString, byteOrderMarkUtf8)
    'Loop
    InString = CleanString
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you verified what's inside the string returned by this: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble())`? Why do you care about the BOM? Where does `InString` come from?

Comment: The string Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble()) appears to return a null ("") in byteOrderMarkUtf8.  I guess that mean I should check for a null before checking to see if CleanString begins or ends with byteOrderMarkUtf8.   InString is a piece of XML for a geographical location.  It looks like this: <Location><X>1740065.852317014200</X><Y>647931.504979122430</Y><Rpa>8301</Rpa><Zone>823</Zone><Precinct>Midtown Hills</Precinct><Zip>37204</Zip><Geom>POINT (1740065.8523170142 647931.50497912243)</Geom><Distance>0.000000000000</Distance></Location>

Comment: That string is not empty, it contains 1 char that translates to `?`. Why do you care about the BOM? Where does `InString` come from? Have you some troubles with string encodings? Also, don't post tons of unformatted stuff in the comments, update your question if you need to add details.

Comment: It's not a null.

Comment: I know that. Can you answer the questions you saw in the previous comments?

Comment: Forget it everybody.  I just stopped looking for a BOM and everything worked just fine.